# Запрос метки [google-data-studio]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, создание-метки

Прошу добавить метку [google-data-studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio).

Пример вопроса: [Google Datastudio как настроить график с группировкой дат по неделям?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1035934)

Я не уверен в массовости данной метки, но она чётко определяет область вопроса.

Google Data Studio имеет поля для расчёта, источники данных, тесно связанна с программированием и графикой.